# Is an svg element in convex hull (path)?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an svg path which I can draw. With `d3js` I calculate a **convex hull** around the path with `d3.geom.hull(...)`. Now I have some svg objects like nodes (svg:circle) and I want to find out whether the node is in the hull or not. How can I realize that? Here is a picture from my svg view:

[image: View of the SVG]

**EDIT:**
My goal is to the node elements in the hull (which are within the path), not only at the edge of the path.

Comment: The [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/) can help with that.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Well you could construct a circle and a polygon and intersect them.

Comment: Could it be that I only get the points if the node is on the edge of the path / polygon?

Comment: Ah yes you're right, seems like this library can't handle this specific case.

Comment: Here's another idea: Place the point behind the hull. Call [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) with the coordinates of the point. If that returns the point, it's outside, if it returns the hull it's inside or on the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do that:

1. Calculate your hull geometry, get back the coordinates array that d3.geom.hull gives you.
2. Add your new point to your original data array and calculate d3.geom.hull again on this array.
3. Compare the array of points returned from step 1 with the array of points returned from step 2 to see if the calculated hull has changed. If it has, then the point is outside the convex hull. If there is no change, then it's inside the convex hull.

This might be performance-intensive if you have a really large dataset.

Here's some simple code to demonstrate:

```
   // Some Random points
   var coords = d3.range(50).map(function() {return [Math.random(),Math.random()]})
   yourHull = d3.geom.hull(coords)
   // Random new point
   newCoord = [Math.random(),Math.random()]
   coords.push(newCoord)
   newHull = d3.geom.hull(coords)

   //The easy case to spot
   if (newHull.length != yourHull.length) {
      console.log("Outside")
   }
   //If the array lengths are the same, the point values may have changed
   else {
   var outside = false;
   for (var x = 0; x < yourHull.length;x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < 2;y++) {
         if (yourHull[x][y] != newHull[x][y]) {
            outside = true;
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   if (outside) {
      console.log("outside")
   }
   else {
      console.log("on the hull")
   }
  }
```

Comment: This won't work if the point is exactly on the hull, will it?

Comment: You mean on the border? With this method, if a point is exactly on the computed hull border, it will register as intersecting with the existing hull (it won't return a different array result).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way of doing this is to have the browser do all the actual work. In particular, use the method [`document.getElementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) to have the rendering engine determine the overlap.

The idea is simple -- add the point you're interested in *behind* the hull, then check whether the above method gives you the point or the hull. The code looks like this.

```
function isInside(point) {
  var c = svg.insert("circle", "path.hull")
    .attr("r", 1)
    .attr("cx", point[0])
    .attr("cy", point[1]);

  var bounds = c.node().getBoundingClientRect();

  var atPoint = document.elementFromPoint(bounds.left, bounds.top);
  var inside = atPoint == c.node() ? false : true;

  c.remove();

  return inside;
}
```

The only slightly tricky bit is to convert the relative coordinates of the point to absolute coordinates -- the above code assumes that the SVG is a top-level element on the page itself or not translated by the containing elements. If this is not the case, adjust the code as appropriate.

The big advantage over the other answer is that the runtime does not depend on the size of the hull (as in the number of points defining it). It only depends on the number of points you want to check.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkj1o883/).

Comment: What does these `c.node()` do? I get an `NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.` error.

Comment: It gets the DOM node object from the D3 selection. You can't call this on an enter selection (I'm guessing that this is what you did). The element needs to exist in the DOM, but you can remove it immediately after checking whether it is obscured by the hull.

Comment: A last question: I save the x and y in a `g` over the circle and not in the `cx`, `cy` attribute. Is there a easy way to access it? Now all results are true because of all nodes looks like the same.

Comment: The coordinates to check are determined by the bounding box of the element, so the method should work regardless of how you position it. Make sure you're using the actual `circle` element (not the `g`) and that its container element isn't translated.

Comment: Ok, than is the problem that the `g`is translated.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) should help with figuring out the position.

Comment: Do I have to add the correct positions to the circle in the `cx` and `cy` attribute?

Comment: No. As I said earlier, this method is using the bounding box to determine the position.

Comment: I add a offset from the svg to the bounds, but now the `atPoint` variable is always the svg element.

Comment: Could you provide a an example of where this goes wrong please?

Comment: I tried it exactly like you do except that my nodes has this structure: `<g><a href..><circle r="6"></circle></a></g>` The position is added with the force layout by d3. I iterate through all nodes, get the coords, and run the method. Now I calculate the offset with var `svg_offset = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getBoundingClientRect(); var offset = [svg_offset.left, svg_offset.top];` and add it to the relative point `var x = pt[0] + offset[0], y = pt[1] + offset[1];`.

Comment: Now it works. I don't change anything to the last comment :/... But thanks for your help!